# Put Excel array values in cache

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large database (700.000+ lines in 20 columns) that I import in Excel and do different manipulations on.

An example of such a manipulation is categorizing. For this I use 2 columns: **material type** and **category** and output it in a column '**Final Category**' by:

```
IF materialType = "SERV" or category = "SERVICE" then finalCategory = "SERVICE"
```

What would be the fastest way to perform this calculation?

Currently I use a FOR loop and already disabled application.screenupdating.

I am also wondering, is there a way to put these columns in cache and then run it?

Hope you can help,

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that the 'materialType' column is A and the 'category' column is B and the 'finalCategory' column is U. Then you can try this:

```
Dim strFormula As String

strFormula = "=IF(OR(A1=""SERV"",B1=""SERVICE""),""SERV"","""")"
Sheet1.Range("U1:U700000").Formula = strFormula
```

This avoids looping over the 700,000 rows and doing an indvidual operation, which can be painfully slow even with no screen updating.